# Does Apache POI support the "strict" variant of ISO/IEC 29500?

Tags: apache-poi, openxml

With M$ Excel 2013 there are 2 variants of XLSX, the "Transitional" which M$ supported with XLSX in Excel 2010, and "Strict" = OOXML. Is POI able to read and write the latter? If so, from which version of POI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and POI 3.5 (though you'd be strongly advised to use 3.9, or wait about a week for a 3.10 beta)

POI uses the official ISO XML schema files to process the XML files, so by default works with the strict (official) form. There's not that much different between the two, but where there is such a difference that matters, POI will have code to munge the low level XML skipping what the schema would normally say.

Answer (score 0):

No, Apache POI does not support Open XML Strict as of this date.

See source: https://helpwanted.apache.org/task.html?5a5d86c834df99c79279b34d6ecdc413107874be